# Javascript .map() is not returning updated array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I'm having an array of date example `[2019-02-21T04:06:32.000Z]` and I want to convert the date into desired format `[02/21/2019 4:06:32 AM]`. So I'm using javascript map

```
dateArray.map( x => {
   return moment.tz(x, 'Etc/UTC').format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A').toString()
});
```

after this I console date array but it is still showing `[2019-02-21T04:06:32.000Z]` but inside map() it is showing in desired format. What I'm doing wrong here? Can any one help me to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Map method returns new array.

Comment: `map` doesn't modify the array _in-place_, it will return a new array instead (use: `dateArray = dateArray.map(...)`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.map` is not mutating the existing array. 
You should do :

```
dataArray = dateArray.map( x => {
  return moment.tz(x, 'Etc/UTC').format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A').toString()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you must change the existing array then use a for loop.

```
dateArray = ['2019-02-21T04:06:32.000Z'];

for(let idx = 0; idx < dateArray.length; idx++){
  dateArray[idx] = moment.tz(dateArray[idx], 'Etc/UTC')
    .format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A').toString();
}
```